# Facing error while including json-c library in visual studio

Tags: c, json, visual-studio

I needed to parse the json file in c code in visual studio. But I am getting errors when I include json-c headers. How can I solve these problems.

```
#include<ntddk.h>
#include<wdf.h>
#include<fwpmk.h>
#include<fwpsk.h>
#define INITGUID
#include<guiddef.h>
#include<fwpmu.h>

#undef _CRT_STRINGIZE
#undef _CRT_WIDE
#undef __CRTDECL
#include<json-c/json.h>
#include<json-c/json_object.h>
```

`The errors are:`

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning C6067   _Param_(2) in call to 'DbgPrint' must be the address of a string. Actual type: 'void *'.    WfpcalloutDriver3   C:\Users\hp\Desktop\VK\WfpcalloutDriver3\Source.c   88  
Warning C4083   expected ')'; found identifier '_VCRUNTIME_DISABLED_WARNINGS'   WfpcalloutDriver3   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\stdint.h    16  
Error   C2220   the following warning is treated as an error    WfpcalloutDriver3   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\vcruntime.h 61  
Warning C4083   expected ')'; found identifier '_VCRUNTIME_DISABLED_WARNINGS'   WfpcalloutDriver3   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\vcruntime.h 61  
Warning C4005   '_CRT_STRINGIZE': macro redefinition    WfpcalloutDriver3   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\vcruntime.h 111 
Warning C4005   '_CRT_WIDE': macro redefinition WfpcalloutDriver3   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\vcruntime.h 114 
Warning C4005   '__CRTDECL': macro redefinition WfpcalloutDriver3   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\vcruntime.h 155
```

Comment: maybe this library doesn't work in drivers

Comment: Please specify your platform.

Comment: I am doing this for windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looked on the [github page](https://github.com/json-c/json-c#using-json-c-) and it says (emphasis mine):

> To use json-c you can either include json.h, **or preferably**, one of the following more specific header files:

```
json_object.h - Core types and methods.
json_tokener.h - Methods for parsing and serializing json-c object trees.
json_pointer.h - JSON Pointer (RFC 6901) implementation for retrieving objects from a json-c object tree.
json_object_iterator.h - Methods for iterating over single json_object instances. (See also json_object_object_foreach() in json_object.h)
json_visit.h - Methods for walking a tree of json-c objects.
json_util.h - Miscellaneous utility functions.
```

So, it looks like you are including json.h *and* json_object.h.  That would explain the macro redefinition.  Try getting rid of `#include<json-c/json.h>`.